# Select Data From SQL DB Using Tableadapter

Tags: c#, .net, tableadapter

Im using a DataSet Designer in My program. in my database I have a primary key "DocumentID" and i want to fetch data from data base using stored Procedure that i Defined in dataset designer and put it in a datatable with below code:

```
dt = patientsTableAdapter1.GetBasic(DNumberEdit.Text);
```

But i got the following error, could you please help me

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `DataSet.EnforceConstraints=false`

More information at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.enforceconstraints(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Did you still receive the same error message? What method did you use to disable the EnforceContraints? Are you able to provide some code?

Comment: DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Clear();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            ds.EnforceConstraints = false;

            dt = patientsTableAdapter1.GetBasic(DNumberEdit.Text);

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see an error with your code, i'm hoping someone else can help you now, as I have recently came across the same problem and setting EnforceConstraints to false, worked for me.